# import php library into Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am new to Cakephp .i want to use the external php  library into my Cakephp web app .. so the directory structure is like that

i have downloaded this dropbox php library from here.. so you can see the directory structure here too
           https://github.com/BenTheDesigner/Dropbox

```
    mydropboxfolder/examples/accountinfo.php
```

at the moment i just want to try the examples first as these works fine when i run them without cakephp

so what  i have done is i  copied the whole folder(mydropboxfolder) into my **app/Lib**

and i changed the file accountinfo.php into class so i added some code like this

```
  class  accountinfo{

public static function getccountinfo(){
  //whole accountinfo class code here
     }
```

and then in Controller i am calling this file

```
  function dropbox()
      App::uses('accountinfo', 'mydropboxfolder/examples');
    accountinfo::account_info();
```

but i am getting these errors

Error: require_once() [http://php.net/function.require'>function.require]: Failed opening required '../Dropbox/OAuth/Storage/Encrypter.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\lib;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\Lib\dropbox\examples\bootstrap.php
Line: 26

i dont know what i am doing wrong .. is that some files are not loading or something else .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

copy your external libraries to App\Vendor folder then use:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'mydropboxfolder/examples/accountinfo');
```

good luck

Comment: i have done as u said but now when i have done this to access the function accountinfo::account_info(); it is saying class not found accountinfo

Comment: $accountinfo=new accountinfo ;
you should create a instance for your class

Comment: Make sure you omit the trailing `.php` file extension. E.g. if the file is just `App\Vendor\MyLib.php`, call `App::import('Vendor', 'MyLib');`